# ACF true/false field returns yes/no instead 1/0

Tags: php, wordpress, boolean, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the Advanced custom fields plugin with my wordpress. The page is based on realia, so I need to display f.e.: Garage Yes/No. Balcony Yes/No, etc.

I have used the true/false field_type, however it always returns 1/0. I would like to receive Yes / No instead (or string defined by myself). I thought, using the true/false. I can't see any setting in ACF to set the return value. Thank you

Comment: Doesn't look like such an option exists for that field type. If you can't handle this in the place where the value actually gets used, then you might either need to use one of ACF's filters to change what gets returned - or solve it using a different field type. For example using radio buttons, those can have a value and a label, and you can specify which one of those you want to get returned.

Comment: Sure, this looks like cleverest way. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to use the Stylised UI of the field. You can set a text on it.

But if you try to get the value programmatically you can always do something like

```
$text = get_field(name) ? 'Yes' : 'No'
```

this will create variable with if else statement. If it's true return 'Yes' otherwise return 'No'.

Comment: I didn't need if else statement, I have needed to display Yes / No information in realia portal for example about garage, electricty, gas availability etc. :)